Flood using smooth brush in sclupting mode
I'm using smooth brush and I want to smooth all the mesh. But rather than paint/sculpt them manually, I prefer to 'flood' it. I can't find a way to flood or apply the smooth brush to the whole mesh using single click.
How to do it ?

Select the mesh filter brush, choose "Smooth" as filter, then click and drag.

